# Django access a list element's attribute in Django template

Tags: python, django

I already know how to access a list element from views to template like this:

*In .html file*

```
{% load index %}
{% lists|index:i %}
```

*In templatetags/index.py*

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def index(indexable, i):
        return indexable[i]
```

However, in my case, each list element contains several attributes which I want to access, like `lists[i].attr`, now I can only access `lists[i]` but not `lists[i].attr`. What can I do?

Comment: why you are not using  simple `for` loop ? `{% for list in lists %} .. {{ list.attr }} .. {% endfor %}`

Comment: `{{ lists.0.attr }}`, `{{ lists.1.attr }}`

Comment: In my case, I need to choose specific element in the list to show its specific attributes. @cizario, This is my code: {% for i in list_length %}
            {% load index %}
            {% if valid_index|index:i == 1 %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ banks_info | index:i:bankname }}</td>
                    <td>{{ banks_info|index:i.city }}</td>
                    <td>{{ banks_info|index:i.money }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}

Comment: @minglyu, the index needs to be a variable not a const value.

Comment: @debug template `tags` and `filters` have to be loaded earlier at the very beginning of your template like {% load static index %}  not inside a loop.

Comment: @cizario OK，I'll change it, but the main problem still remains.